# Create dataValidation from named list in different sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi

i'm trying to create a dataValidation object with a List Constraint being the name of a ranged single contiguous column .... The list which i would pass on as argument to the createFormulaListConstraint() is in a different sheet than where i would like to display the dataValidation. 
The following is the code that i have so far and when i try to run it a **FormulaParseException: Specified name range does not exist in the current workbook** is being thrown:

```
    Name name = dctmWorkSheet.getWorkbook().createName();
    name.setSheetIndex(1);
    name.setNameName(cell.getStringCellValue());    
    name.setRefersToFormula(getRangeRefersToFormula(valueAssSheet, firstRow, rowIndex, insertCol));

    validationHelper = dctmWorkSheet.getDataValidationHelper();
    //------ THIS IS THE LINE RESPONSIBLE FOR THE EXCEPTION -------
    constraint = validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint(name.getNameName());
    dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, cral);
    dataValidation.setEmptyCellAllowed(true);
    dataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    dataValidation.setErrorStyle(DataValidation.ErrorStyle.STOP);
    dataValidation.createErrorBox("Error", "Please use Pick List Value");
    dctmWorkSheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```

Thanks for any help or feedback......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually managed to solve my problem by creating an additional name to sheetIndex(0) and reference it to the name in sheetIndex(1)....
The following is the code which works as desired:

```
    Name name = dctmWorkSheet.getWorkbook().createName();
    name.setSheetIndex(1);
    name.setNameName(cell.getStringCellValue());    
    name.setRefersToFormula(getRangeRefersToFormula(valueAssSheet, firstRow, rowIndex, insertCol));
    Name name2 = dctmWorkSheet.getWorkbook().createName();
    name2.setSheetIndex(0);
    name2.setNameName(name.getNameName());
    name2.setRefersToFormula(name.getRefersToFormula());


    validationHelper = dctmWorkSheet.getDataValidationHelper();
    constraint = validationHelper.createFormulaListConstraint(name2.getNameName());
    dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint, cral);
    dataValidation.setEmptyCellAllowed(true);
    dataValidation.setShowErrorBox(true);
    dataValidation.setErrorStyle(DataValidation.ErrorStyle.STOP);
    dataValidation.createErrorBox("Error", "Please use Pick List Value");
    dctmWorkSheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);
```